# Событие установки приложения

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Как можно отследить, что приложения было установлено?
Допустим, при установке надо слать HTTP запрос.
Где и что нужно прописать?
В MainActivity? Или в манифесте где-то?

При этом код должен срабатывать только при установке APK или с гугл плея.

Comment: Да, где это можно прописать там и пропишите, что за вопросы такие странные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вы ищете, называется Broadcast Reception. Данная технология доступна всем разработчикам и предназначена она для "прослушивания" всех событий, происходящих в системе Android. Тема это обширная, и если вы с ней не знакомы, то это плохо. Обязательно ознакомьтесь!

Существует огромное количество событий, которые вы можете "поймать" и обработать. Среди них есть и те, что нужны вам:

- **[ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)**
- **[ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)**

Данное событие транслирует сама система при установке нового APK. Зарегистрировав собственный широковещательный приемник в манифесте, вы сможете реагировать на это действие системы. Подробнее об использовании можете почитать **[здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470314/receiving-package-install-and-uninstall-events)**, например.